# What is compiler diagnostic?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, language-lawyer, compiler-warnings

I usually say "compiler warning", "compiler error". So when hear "compiler diagnostic messages" or just "compiler diagnostic" I'm a little unsure are they just usual "compiler warning", "compiler error" or something different?

Comment: In short, it's all the messages (warning and errors) produced by the compiler.

Answer (score 7):

A diagnostic message is actually defined by the standard as

> [**[defns.diagnostic]**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/defns.diagnostic)
>
> message belonging to an implementation-defined subset of the
>   implementation's output messages

Which is any message, in any form an implementation chooses to present. Both warnings and errors printed to console fall under this definition. But it is not limited to console or even just warnings or errors. For instance, an implementation may choose to display an "info" message in a popup. That is also a potential diagnostic message.

Comment: standardese is hard in general, but I find this wording particularly strange. why is the subset implementation-defined? Is this to allow also those compiler messages that are not mandated by the standard to be called "diagnostic"?

Comment: maybe the implementation-defined refers to: the implementation may choose how the message actually looks like. On first read I though the "implementation defined" refers to: the implementation can choose what output messages do belong to the subset

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 - I think it's actually your first read that has it right. An implementation may present messages that are unrelated to diagnostics. I think this definition just points out that an implementation may choose to communicate with the programmer with more messages than the bare minimum required.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 The wording allows several freedoms to the implementation. It allows the implementation to output messages that are not diagnostics.  It allows a choice of whether the messages it emits are in different forms (e.g. "warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]", the equivalent in Klingon, or a numeric code of 42).  It allows a choice of how the message is presented (e.g. text output, window popup).  The possibilities are endless.

Comment: @Peter if I had to choose between 42 and Klingon I wouldnt know what to pick. Thanks for the input. I guess sometimes it is not worth trying to interpret to much into it, I mean its a document meant to communicate between the comitee and compiler writers and they all know how to use common sense (hopefully ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818    ghuHmoH: integer chenmoH initialization vo' pointer Hutlh woDlu'chugh [-wint-conversion]

Answer (score 0):

"Diagnostic message" is a term of art in the C++ standard. Chances are that when someone says "compiler diagnostic" they're vaguely thinking of that term, but not applying it correctly.

The standard has several categories for things in code that don't meet the requirements of the standard, and the way that the compiler is allowed to respond depends on which category the error fits into.

Most of the requirements in the standard are in "the set of **diagnosable rules**". Those rules consist of all of the syntactic and semantic requirements in the standard except those that are explicitly marked "no diagnostic required" and those which are described as resulting in "undefined behavior". (Thats from [intro.compliance]/1).

If the program violates a diagnosable rule a conforming implementation "shall issue at least one diagnostic message".

So, broadly speaking, most coding errors require a diagnostic message. Now that just leaves open the question of what constitutes a "diagnostic message", and that's defined in the standard as a "message belonging to an implementation-defined subset of the implementation's output messages".

That means that the compiler can talk to you all it wants or as little as it wants, except that when certain coding errors are detected, it has to say something to you.

So when the compiler tells you that you should add parentheses around the `||` operations in `if (a && b || c && d)` it's just babbling. The code is valid and its meaning is well defined, and it's just giving you style advice (and bad advice at that).

When it tells you that it doesn't know the type of `x` in `typedef int foo; fo0 x;` it's responding to a diagnosable error. If the implementation's documentation tells you that that message is a diagnostic message, then that's what it is. And generally that's what compilers do.

Note that the compiler is **not** required to refuse to compile code that has a diagnosable error. The **only** requirement is to issue a diagnostic message. Having done that, the compiler is free to continue to compile the code, with an implementation-specific result. The main reason for that flexibility is that it allows compiler-specific extensions.

Compilers generally distinguish between warnings and errors; the standard does not. It does require that, when presented with code that does not violate any of the standard's requirements, and if the program isn't too big (in a vague sense), the compiler must create an executable program. Formally, that's "If a program contains no violations of the rules in this International Standard, a conforming implementation shall, within its resource limits, accept and correctly execute that program." [intro.compliance]/2.

Answer (score 0):

Much of the value in many standards lies not merely in the things they require all conforming instances to do, but in the things they recommend that quality instances should do when practical.  The authors of the C89 Standard, however, went out of their way to avoid offering any such recommendations for anything that wasn't required.  If C89 had recommended e.g. that implementations process relational operators on pointers in a fashion consistent with a global transitive relation, that might have been seen as implying that implementations where that would be impractical were somehow inferior.

The authors of the Standard didn't want to forbid conforming implementations from usefully processing code that predated the Standard and doesn't satisfy its requirements, but also didn't particularly want to imply that implementations should accept new code that doesn't meet requirements.  Requirements that a conforming implementation must meaningfully process *at least one* program, or that an implementation given a source text that violates compile-time constraints must produce *at least one* diagnostic, are something of a dodge between hard requirements and recommendations.  Presumably, a quality implementation should be able to usefully process something other than a single contrived (and possibly useless) source text, and should produce some diagnostics that are more useful than "Warning: this implementation won't output any diagnostics other than this one", but an implementation could satisfy the Standard without going beyond the above.